# tiny mce js throwing maven build type conversion error

Tags: maven, build, compiler-errors, tinymce, classcastexception

While including the JS file for tiny mce in the js folder when trying to build the application i am getting the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject cannot be cast to java.lang.String
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.InterpolationFilterReader.read(InterpolationFilterReader.java:269)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.InterpolationFilterReader.read(InterpolationFilterReader.java:162)
        at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:123)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.IOUtil.copy(IOUtil.java:212)
```

i am not sure why including a js file is throwing this weired build error.

Any help in this regard is highly appriciated

Vaibhav

Comment: Can you post the pom file ?

Comment: i cant post the pom here its too long to be posted as a comment, if you wish i can add some specific parts of it

Comment: Which Maven version do you use? Please provide the result for `mvn -v`.

Comment: You don't post it as a comment, but rather -- as an edit of your question. Please, post you `pom.xml`.

Comment: 3.8.8$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 2.0.11 (r909250; 2010-02-12 11:25:50+0530)
Java version: 1.6.0_22
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.31-22-generic" arch: "i386" Family: "unix"

Comment: Regarding to the issue: [Problem using webResources in configuration](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MWAR-109). The may be the suitable time to upgrade your Maven.